# Android runtime permissions dialog not showing

Tags: java, android, permissions

I am trying to get permissions (from users running versions of Android higher than 6.0) for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION at runtime. This was unsuccessful in my main app so I tried making a test app with a sole purpose of requesting location permissions from the user.

The problem I am having is that no permissions dialog box is being shown to the user - from the logcat I can see that the 'onRequestPermissionsResult' method is being run straight away (without asking the user to accept permissions), and it is showing that permissions were not granted.

After looking through other questions around this topic, I have double checked that the 'uses-permission' line is in my Android Manifest XML file, but couldn't find any other solution.

Here is my code:

```
package com.user.testapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_ID = 1;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkLocationPermissions();
}

private void checkLocationPermissions(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Device version above 6.0 - Requesting location permissions.");
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION_ID);
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_LOCATION_ID: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Permissions granted successfully!");

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Permissions were not granted.");
            }
            return;
        }
    }//end switch
}

}//end class
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.user.testapplication">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And the relevant lines from the logcat:

```
11-27 13:27:47.752 31839-31839/com.user.testapplication I/MainActivity: Device version above 6.0 - Requesting location permissions.
11-27 13:27:47.881 31839-31839/com.user.testapplication I/MainActivity: Permissions were not granted.
```

Any help is much appreciated - I think I may just be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in onStart() method, it will solve your issue.

```
 //This checks for the permission
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){


            // You can show your dialog message here but instead I am 
            // showing the grant permission dialog box
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
                    10);



        }
        else{

            //Requesting permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
                    10);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jack, unfortunately I am having the same issue still. The Activity shows on screen but there is no prompt for any permissions. Using logs to check, the onStart method runs, and the second branch of the if statement executes. No box is displayed on screen, and a call to the requestPermissionsResult method is made, resulting in "Permissions were not granted" to be output to the log.

Comment: The possible reason is once that permission box was displayed for the very first time, you would have chosen the checkbox that says "Never show this again" and then you had denied this permission. What you can do is clear the data of the app and then run again or simply uninstall the app and install it again. Hope it will work.

Comment: I uninstalled the app and then ran the program again and got the same result. I was wondering whether there needs to be any explicit pause called or a 'wait for input' is needed/possible in Android?

Comment: Of course, in your activity you need to do something that actually needs permission, otherwise that box will never be shown. Like if you want the permission of phone identity (IMEI number) and then this line should be added to use the phone identity permission else the permission box wouldn't come up. 


`TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
   String id=mngr.getDeviceId();`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that and I think that is why the box is not being shown. Would you do a check for permissions before the request that needs phone identity is made, or afterwards in a catch block for an exception?

Comment: You can put the code in try block that needs permission(Like the one I used in the comment above) and in catch block you can put the one I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Okay thanks Jack I will try and do this, I think that will fix my problem.

Comment: or you could just use my [permission library](https://github.com/hendraanggrian/permission), declare `TelephonyManager` in onGranted().

Comment: Hendra, I just gave him an example, he doesn't want the TelephonyManager stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for no `Dialog` box being shown was a typo in the `AndroidManifest`, you can see that the permission was spelt `android-permisssion` rather than `android-permission`.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem my issue was i had written following line in manifest

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

instead of

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```